# Spring security OAuth2

Tags: spring, security, oauth-2.0

I've setup an OAuth2 server with spring security. I've been following the `tonr2` and `sparklr2` examples online. I've been able to make requests just fine to get an `auth_token` from my server.

The problem arises when I try to make a request to retrieve data using the auth token.
The request seems to work ONLY if I send it through Firefox, where a correct `SecurityContextHolder` is setup. Trying to send it through Chrome or cURL fails, since

> 03/03/2012 17:18:36 DEBUG [39f42b5dda]:
>   nymousAuthenticationFilter(107): SecurityContextHolder not populated
>   with anonymous token, as it already contained:
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@f9990c8d:
>   Principal: 576-test@test.com; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated:
>   true; Details:
>   org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@0:
>   RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: 1hul55tre0gm81uff741z2myg9;
>   Granted Authorities: ROLE_USER'

Was wondering what the issue may be?

The url I'm trying to hit is:

```
http://localhost:8080/optimal-security/users/me?format=json&access_token=e56996a1-edad-4a59-bb80-50d520fdca1f
```

The requests (as grabbed from WireShark):

Firefox:

```
GET /optimal-security/users/me?format=json&access_token=6e984103-e38f-4e5b-a652-d3419b8bab54 
HTTP/1.1..Host: localhost:8080..
User-Agent:Mozilla /5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.6;en-US; rv:1.9.2.12) Gecko/20101026 Fire fox/3.6.12..
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+ xml,application/ xml;q=0.9,*/*;q= 0.8..
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q =0.5..
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate..
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1, utf-8;q=0.7,*;q= 0.7..
Keep-Alive: 115..Connection : keep-alive..
Cookie: JSESSIONID =1e9qxdzom44fr1t brdcjlts 9yw; JSESSIONID=238244B4 C0DAB2311794E4BC A2833E5C
```

Chrome:

```
GET /optimal-security/users/me?format=json&access_token=6e984103-e38f-4e5b-a652-d3419b8bab54 
HTTP/1.1..Host: localhost:8080..Connection:keep-alive..
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh;Intel M ac OS X 10_6_8) AppleWebKit/535. 11 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/17 .0.963.56 Safari /535.11..
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml ,application/xml ;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8 ..
Accept-Language: en-US,en; q=0.8..
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate, sdch..
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859- 1,utf-8;q=0.7,*; q=0.3..
Cookie: JSESSIONID=9cguv6 hkgeknzlxelqm1py ux....
```

Still can't figure out what special thing is being done with FF so that it works?

Comment: Ok...figured out part of the problem. It was due to the fact that when a request was being made to the OAuth server for the token, the server would set a cookie with the JSESSIONID in Firefox, which was being used to authenticate any subsequent requests.

But the problem still remains, how to use Spring OAuth2 to respond to a request that has a valid access token? The request fails at the anonymousAuthenticationFilter check. How do I setup a request to get past that?

Comment: Can you see any evidence of the `OAuth2AthenticationProcessingFilter` kicking in (it would show up in DEBUG logs)? Note: it is highly deprecated to use a query parameter for the access token (not very secure), so I'd try and switch that if I were you.